# Injecting Property in Quarkus Scala as an Option

Tags: scala, quarkus

I am trying to use quarkus app with scala as the language and facing problem injecting a property as an option. I have tried `_, None and Some(_)`. What is the right way to inject a optional property.

```
package org.acme

import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.ws.rs.{GET, Path, PathParam, Produces}
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty

@Path("/hello")
class GreetingResource @Inject() (service: GreetingService){

    @ConfigProperty(name = "greeting.message")
    var message: String = _

    @ConfigProperty(name = "greeting.suffix", defaultValue="!")
    var suffix: String = _

    @ConfigProperty(name = "greeting.name")
    var name: Option[String] = _

    def this() = this(null)

    @GET 
    @Path("/greeting/{name}")
    @Produces(Array[String](MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    def greeting(@PathParam("name") name: String): String = service.greeting(name)

    @GET 
    @Produces(Array[String](MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    def hello() = s"${message} world${suffix}" 
}
```

Facing this error,
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Converter registered for class scala.Option`

Comment: Why read that as an option ? You can read the property as a `String` like you did for all others. Or you can implement the custom converter for your DI.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh that true, I can read it as an option. Java equivalent is working with Optional, I am trying to find the scala equivalent.

Comment: Or you can read it as a nullable string and create another method that returns Option - None when the string is null or empty. It is more work, but it should work. Though the best would be implement a converter.

Comment: It’2 years later, what did you do in the end, if you recall that is?